# Sending HTTP packet via powershell or other means

Tags: powershell, http, command, packet

So I am asking this question for my sysadmin. We have a rather large print server, with over 250 copiers. Currently, to adjust configuration we have to use a web GUI and go through a bunch of clicks per IP address. With 250+ copiers, this is very time consuming. We are looking for a way to bulk configure these copiers by executing a process. I have captured the packet that adjusts the setting on the copier. I was hoping there might be someone out there who knows if it is possible to take this HTTP packet and somehow transmit this packet to all copiers with the press of a button, and automating the whole process. I have very light knowledge of packets and the protocols associated with them, but if someone has the knowledge, I would love to pick your brain...

Comment: I don't really understand what you expect now.. StackOverflow is not a Coding Service. Please take a look at [ask] and try to offer an [mcve] of what you tried so far.
Also a good way to get started in easy Powershell Web-Scripting is to read Owens Blog: https://foxdeploy.com/2018/04/02/faster-web-cmdlet-design-with-chrome-65/

Comment: Generally, you can use `Invoke-RestMethod()` and `Invoke-WebRequest()` when dealing with HTTP. Check this article: https://www.systemcenterautomation.com/2018/05/invoke-restmethod-vs-invoke-webrequest/   and this SU post: https://superuser.com/questions/1235349/what-is-the-difference-between-invoke-webrequest-and-invoke-restmethod

Comment: I find it hard to imagine that your copier vendor doesn't have a configuration management system of some kind or an API of some kind. Rather than spending resources on a narrow solution that requires reverse engineering, why not a general solution to the problem of copier management? Which vendor have you got?

Comment: @Paxz I guess what I'm asking is not for someone to write the code to do this, moreso if it is possible to take a premade HTTP packet and forward it to ip addresses from a list. I am totally capable of writing script to do this portion in powershell, but am lost when it comes to packets. I sense that this might be way above my level of skill, but I was moreso looking for a discussion on possibilities. I apologize if this isnt the correct medium for doing so. I appreciate the link, and will read into it. Thank you

Comment: @BaconBits We are using PaperCut management. Unfortunately, on their website I am only able to find documentation on doing this one by one. We are trying to disable WSD on all copiers so that they are not discoverable and cannot be directly printed to.

Comment: @trebleCode Thank you sir, these articles seem like they will get me on the right path after just glancing over them... I will look into them more!